# Why does MSE think I "modified" an answer?

Tags: bug, frontpage

I answered [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479740/prove-x3-3-4yy1-has-no-integer-solutions) this morning.  A little later I noticed on the list-of-recent-questions MSE homepage that I had "modified" something there instead of "answered."  Neither my answer nor anything else at the question indicate any edits (by me or anyone else), so I'm just curious why the homepage thinks I modified instead of answered.

This isn't a screenshot, but here's what I grabbed from the recent-questions list:

Prove x3+3=4y(y+1)x334yy1 has no integer solutions
algebra-precalculus elementary-number-theory proof-strategy modified 27 mins ago Barry Cipra

[image: screenshot]

**Added later**:  I should perhaps clarify that the MSE homepage I'm referring to has url simply "http://math.stackexchange.com" (with nothing extra after the "com").  Here's a typical screenshot of what I see:

[image]

The activity status is a mix of "asked," "answered," and "modified."  The "modified" indicator normally means something has been changed, and the change can be found in an appropriate edit history.  But, again, there were *no* edits of any sort at the question I'm asking about.  So I'm just curious how that status got attached to my answer.  (It's not a big deal that it did, I really am just curious.)

Comment: This depends a bit on whether you view questions sorted by [activity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-number-theory?sort=active&pageSize=50) or by [time of posting](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-number-theory?sort=newest&pageSize=50). The later always shows when the question was asked. You may also notice that if you hover over the timestamp, it will show the time of the last activirty and if you click on it, it will skip to the part which was most recently posted or edited.

Comment: I have added screenshot to your post. Of course, feel free to remove it if does not help to clarify your question.

Comment: This MSE post gives some explanation http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260915/why-are-all-posts-in-active-tab-displayed-as-modified but it does not quite line up with what I observe now.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, thank you for the screenshot.  It's evidently from a different "homepage" than I use, since it includes an opening excerpt from the problem statement, but it's still helpful.  (Also, I didn't know about the hovering-over-the-timestamp feature, so thank you that as well.)  I've added a sample screenshot from the homepage I use.